# ¿Cómo puedo instanciar objetos recorriendo una lista con un atributo de estos? java

Tags: java, clase

Lo que pasa es que tengo una serie de clases que definen animales, y todas extienden a una clase general ser vivo, el problema es que necesito instanciar estos animales dentro de varios ecosistemas y no sé cómo hacerlo, por ejemplo, tengo una lista `animal = {"conejo","leon"}` y otra `cant_animal = {4,2}`, y las clases `Leon`y`Conejo` (hijas de la clase `SerVivo`) que poseen el atributo `nombre` en ellas. ¿Como puedo instanciarlas dentro de un `for` o algo asi sin escribir a que clase pertenecen?

Answer (score 1):

En java existen las Reflection, que te permiten trabajar con las clases sin tener que usar la propia clase, por ejemplo podrías instanciar un objeto de la clase Leon de la siguiente forma:

```
Class<?> miClase = Class.forName("Leon");
Constructor<?> constructor = miClase .getConstructor(String.class);
Object objetoLeon= constructor.newInstance("nombre de mi leon");
```

No se si esto te servirá pero si quieres una respuesta más concreta deberías aportar algo más a la pregunta, como un código de ejemplo o algo que hayas intentado ya tu mismo.